# Assigning template file to a view

Tags: views, entities

How to display the custom content type fiels in the custom template file. I have integrated custom content types in views.

How to assign custom template files to a view which is filtered to display certain content type only.

Comment: I seen the templatefiles in themes information. There are various template files for all the fields created in the content type. Which template file have to be used to display all the field information based on our HTML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656)

For content types you can try

**node--[type|nodeid].tpl.php**

*base template: node.tpl.php*

Theme hook suggestions are made based on these factors, listed from the most specific template to the least. Drupal will use the most specific template it finds:

1. node--nodeid.tpl.php
2. node--type.tpl.php
3. node.tpl.php

**To theme a view..**

1. Set up your view; by going to Views -> Add View
2. Once, your view is completely set up, at the bottom of the view (left column), you will see a link called "Theme Information", click on it.
3. What you will be presented with is a list of templates (.tpl.php) files that the views uses to theme your data. Basically the file names that are bolded are the files views is using to theme the data.

Check [How to create a Custom Template for a View](http://www.wdtutorials.com/drupal7/49)

Comment: In Wordpress we can assign a particular template file for the page. Similarly how to assign the template file for the particular custom content type

Comment: I have the content type(Testimonials) I have integrated fields into views. Now I want guidance, how to show all the node of the content type in one custom template file. Please kindly guide me

Comment: Create a file named `node--testimonials.tpl.php` put it in your theme folder. clear cache check whether it works. let me know

Comment: It is not taking that file. I added testimonial link in the main menu. When I click "Testimonial" in main menu. It takes default page.tpl file. Any changes has to be done in the views

Comment: @sindhu Give the machine name of content type.

Comment: Machine name is testimonials . I have given that

Comment: Which is the enabled theme ? make sure your `tpl` is in correct folder and clear cache as well

Comment: @ Nikhil M, i think she is looking for views templates, it is mentioned that she selected content type in view and  'seen the templatefiles in themes information.'

Comment: @AnoopJoseph, hmm i think so too :) see my edit.

Comment: tpl file is in the enables theme folder. I used views and added the content type fields in that

Comment: @sindhu see the link in my edited answer.

Comment: http://www.wdtutorials.com/drupal7/49#.UUaX5TdfTxV . I done based on this link

Comment: This displays in front page. I want it to be displayed when i click in the main menu

Comment: @sindhu then t should work :)

Comment: @sindhu click on Create a Page as in http://www.wdtutorials.com/sites/default/files/imceimages/6-8.jpg and give it a path add the path to main menu.

Comment: Thank you Nikhil. I points the file now. I'm trying to render the field value.

Comment: @sindhu consider choosing my answer as correct answer if this helps you to find out the issue. click on the tick icon just below the up/down arrows.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7961/discussion-between-sindhu-and-nikhil-m)